# Accessing Controller object from outside AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

In case we use the following syntax for declaring a controller:

```
<div ng-app="scopeExample" ng-controller="MyController as ctrl">
    <input id="box" ng-model="ctrl.num"> equals {{ ctrl.num }}   
</div>

<script> 
angular.module('scopeExample', [])
.controller('MyController', [function () {
     this.num=12;
}]);
</script>
```

it is easy to access the **controller object** by:

```
var x=angular.element('#box').scope().ctrl
```

If we use the following syntax:

```
<div ng-app="scopeExample" ng-controller="MyController">
     <input id="box" ng-model="number"> equals {{ number }}   
</div>

angular.module('scopeExample', []).
controller('MyController', ['$scope', function MyController($scope) {$scope.number=124;
  this.num = 369;}]);
```

***how can we access the Controller object itself from outside AngularJS?*** Inside AngularJS, more specifically inside .controller method, it is accessible via **this**. In other words, where do we find **num** property?

Comment: May I know why you wanted to mix `this` & `$scope` together? It sounds bad Idea to me. And for accessing `this` context of controller, you should have `controllerAs` pattern use which put value inside `scope.aliasName` keyword and make `this` content accessible via it..

Comment: That's a dangerous idea to get your controller from outside of Angular anyway. Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't get controller from your scope. It's better to use `controller as` syntax as stated [here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y031)

Also note what's written there

> The controllerAs syntax uses this inside controllers which gets bound to $scope

This means, otherwise it's not bound to $scope.